# How to store multiple movie titles in an array in java using a for loop

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse, for-loop

I currently am working on a project for school, in which I must prompt multiple  movie titles, and the amount of copies of each movie and store them in an array. However, it appears as though each time I ask for a new title, it writes over the last title(s). I currently have two files `rentalplace.java` and `video.java` (the contents of both are included at the bottom). Currently I am prompting for only 3 movies to be entered. It looks something like this:

> Title of Video?
> lion king
> Number of Copies?
> 3
> Title of Video?
> finding
>   nemo
> Number of Copies?
> 5
> Title of Video?
> Monsters inc.
> Number of
>   Copies?
> 1

What happens when you input these answers is on the last iteration
(where I put in *"Monsters inc."*) will be what prints for all the spaces in the array. Like this:

> Title ----------#copies-------#Available
>  
>  Monsters
>   inc-----1---------------1
>  
>  Monsters
>   inc-----1---------------1
>  
>  Monsters
>   inc-----1---------------1

I need to find a way to do this without overwriting the previous values in the array so that the first position `[0]` will show up as *"Lion king"* and the second position `[1]` will show up as *"Finding Nemo"*.

My Code: `rentalplace.java`

```
package videolibrary;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class rentalplace {
    public static void printAll(int current, video[] varray) {
        System.out.println("Title" + "\t" + "Number of" + "\t" + "Number   Available");
        for (int i = 0; i <= varray.length; i++) {
            varray[i].print();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int current = 0, max = 10;
        video[] varray = new video[max];
        video v = new video();
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            v.addVideo();
            varray[j] = v;
            current++;
        }
        printAll(current, varray);
    }
}
```

`video.java`:

```
package videolibrary;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class video {
    private String title;
    private int NumberOf;
    private int NumAvailable;
    private Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public void addVideo() {
        System.out.println("Title of video?");
        title = keyboard.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Number of copies?");
        NumberOf = keyboard.nextInt();
        String nothing = keyboard.nextLine();
        NumAvailable = NumberOf;
    }

    public void addNum(int NumToAdd) {
        NumberOf = NumberOf + NumToAdd;
        NumAvailable = NumAvailable + NumToAdd;
    }

    public void removeNum(int NumToRem) {
        NumberOf = NumberOf - NumToRem;
        NumAvailable = NumAvailable - NumToRem;
    }

    public void checkOut() {
        if (NumAvailable > 0)
            NumAvailable--;
        else
            System.out.println("Sorry " + title + " is not available at this time.");
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(title + " \t " + NumberOf + " \t " + NumAvailable);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please also read the [Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html). For example your class names should start with a capital letter: *Rentalplace* and *Video* and variables (like methods) should start with a lowercase letter, like: *numberOf* or *numAvailable*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`video v = new video();` should be inside the loop. Otherwise you'll be adding the same `video` instance to the array multiple times.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int current=0, max = 10;
    video[] varray = new video[max];
    for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
        video v = new video();
        v.addVideo();
        varray[j]=v;
        current++;  
    }
    printAll(current, varray);  
}
```